# How to round nested list into 2 decimal places in python?

Tags: python

I have the nested list as following:

```
 A=[[2,3.55,40.9998],[53.656,65.9],[0.2222]]
```

How to round to 2 decimal places for the A, below is my expected output:

```
 A=[[2.00,3.55,41.00],[53.66,65.90],[0.22]]
```

I try to used round(A,2) but not able, anyone can share me some ideas?

Comment: Do you need to modify the list, or just format it for printing?

Comment: i need to modify the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to modify the list, you'll have to iterate over it with either a for loop

```
for sublst in A:
    for i, val in enumerate(sublst):
        sublst[i] = round(val, 2)
```

or a nested list comprehension

```
new_A = [[round(val, 2) for val in sublst] for sublst in A]
```

---

For what it's worth, if you only needed to format for printing, you could use string formatting.

```
for line in A:
    print(" ".join(map("{:.2f}".format, line)))
    # equivalent to
    print(" ".join([{:.2f}.format(val) for val in line]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can go for format function, for example:

a = 2
print(format(a, '.2f'))

The result will be: 2.00